# Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) - Reposting

Tags: django

***Please do not close my question again if you are not sure that the answer provide to others fit my case.***

I am deploying a django app for the first time to Heroku. I used the following:

heroku run python manage.py migrate

and it returns :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

In my settings.py i have :

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

and at the bottom :

```
try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

in the local_settings.py I have :

```
DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'newapp_development',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '#####',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

my .gitignore file looks like:

```
# byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]

# tests and coverage
*.pytest_cache
.coverage

# database & logs
*.db
*.sqlite3
*.log

# venv
env
venv

# other
.DS_Store

# javascript
package-lock.json

staticfiles/*
!staticfiles/.gitkeep 
!/core/local_settings.py
```

Do you know why is the error message  please ?
Also, note that local_settings is added to . gitignore.

I did a few search on search engine and the responses that i found did not work for me or were not clear enough to me. This is the reason why I took the risk of asking publicly here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure your local_settings.py is not in your git repo? Kind of looks like it

Comment: Did you put the .gitignore file AFTER adding local_settings.py to your repo?

Comment: @dustin-we I have just added the .gitignore file to the description.

Comment: Educated guess: Remove the leading "/" in last line of gitignore file -> "!core/local_settings.py"

Comment: And then remove core/local_settings.py from git repo ("git rm --cached core/local_settings.py" keeps your local copy, but removes remote one)

Comment: @MikeS, i did both removing the "/" and removing the cahed core/local_settings, the error is still the same

Comment: Have cou commited and pushed the remove?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found, the approach that I used works perfectly to manage two different db with two settings files.
What was wrong, was .env file which came with the template that I used. it had the following :

```
DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

deleting this line makes it work both in production and locally.

Thank you guys for helping me eliminate the potential problems down to the main one.

And to those who downgraded my question,...not much to say actually.